# Valid Sass Map Returning Error in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

I am encountering an error when my Rails 4 app is compiling a Sass file when containing the following code:

(Simplified for discussion purposes)

```
$map: (red: #ff0000, green: #00ff00, blue: #0000ff);

@each $color-name, $color-value in $map {
  .#{$color-name} {
    background: $color-value;
  }
}
```

This validates on sassmeister.com but returns an error when compiled in Rails app. The error is: "Invalid CSS after "$map: (red": expected ")", was ": #ff0000, gree..."

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Only in versions of Sass that don't support mappings.

Answer (score 0):

I have also had the same error and was running sass 3.3.7, an upgrade to sass 3.3.8 didn't work but installing the alpha version of compass did fix it (https://rubygems.org/gems/compass/versions/1.0.0.alpha.13). 
If you're using compass the current stable version does not seem to support sass maps but the 1.0 does.